# Calculus, $i = 2 \cos (50πt - 0.4)$ Determine the minimum value and time when this minimum occurs.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, maxima-minima

I have this question about minima and maxima. I have found the derivative of
$i = 2 \cos (50πt - 0.4)$

**$\frac{di}{dt}$** $=-100π \sin(50πt - 0.4)$

From here I attempt to find the turning points by making the derivative equal zero and solving for it. I have the final equation and steps below.

$0 = -100π \sin(50πt - 0.4)$

$100π = \sin(50πt - 0.4)$

*$\sin^{-1}$* $(100π) = 50πt - 0.4$

*$\sin^{-1}$* $(2) = t - 0.4$

*$\sin^{-1}$* $(2) +0.4 = t$

This can't be right as you are unable to get an inverse sine value over $1$, my calculator simply says error.

Where have I gone wrong in trying to find the turning point of the derivative?

Comment: How did $100\pi$ change into 2?  You can't cancel it when it is an argument. Also $sin^{-1}$ has a domain of $[-1,1]$

Comment: The step from $0 = -100π \sin(50πt - 0.4)$ to $100π = \sin(50πt - 0.4)$ is wrong. You just can cancel the constant $-100π$.

Comment: I bring the 100π, I then divide the whole equation by 50π. on the left hand side I have sin-1 100π/50π and that equals 2

Comment: For the turning points you will need the second derivative of $$i(t)$$

Comment: I thought the method for finding the turning points was to solve the first derivative for zero, and the second derivative tells you whether those turning points are minima or maxima? 

Should I solve the second derivative for zero?

Comment: @Zibraz313 "I thought the method for finding the turning points was to solve the first derivative for zer0" You´re right. Btw, have you read my comment.#

Comment: @callculus So I can simply cancel the -100π and solve the equation 0=sin(50πt - 0.4) to determine the turning points?

Comment: @Zibraz313 That´s true and forget the comment of Dr. Sonnhard Graubner. The answer of nmasanta shows the right calculation.

Comment: @Zibraz313 Please leave a comment if it is all clear now or not.

Comment: That should be ok. Thats cleared everything. Sometimes the other commenters makes things more confusing. Thanks:)

Comment: @Zibraz313 That´s nice to hear. It would be nice as well if you accept the answer of nmasanta. Yes, some users make mistakes and don´t leave a comment when they notice their mistakes. This behavior causes many confusions

Answer (score 1):

$0 = -100π \sin(50πt - 0.4)\implies \sin(50πt - 0.4)=0 \implies 50πt - 0.4=n\pi$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Now $ 50πt - 0.4=n\pi\implies t=\frac{n\pi+0.4}{50\pi}$, for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need any calculus at all. The minimum values of a cosine are all $-1$ and they come when the argument is an odd multiple of $\pi$.

So your minimum value is $-2$.

It happens in infinitely many places. One of them is given by $$50\pi t-0.4=\pi$$

Comment: I understand how to determine the minimum value, and I am able to do it through simply rearranging the equation but this question I had was for differential calculus. I use calculus to mathematically determine whether the first turning point is a minimum or maximum.